# Map multiple items to a value in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3, 100], "b": [4,5,6, 50]})
```

I want to replace values (4, 5, 6) in column b with  50. I can use the following code:

```
vals_to_replace1 = {4:10, 5:10, 6:10}
df['b'] = df['b'].map(vals_to_replace1)
```

But I have a long list of items that I need to replace with only one value. I tried this solution: 
`vals_to_replace = {[4,5,6]:10}`. But it does not work. Is there any simple method to do this mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html).

```
my_list = [4,5,6]
val = 10
df['b'] = df['b'].replace(my_list,val)
```

Or creating  a **dict**:

```
df['b'] = df['b'].replace(dict(zip(my_list,[val]*len(my_list))))

#Or Series.map + fillna
#df['b'] = ( df['b'].map(dict(zip(my_list,[val]*len(my_list))))
#                   .fillna(df['b']) )
```

We could also use [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html).

```
m = df['b'].isin(my_list)
```

---

Then you can use [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
df.loc[m,'b'] = val
```

or [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html)

```
df['b']=df['b'].mask(m,val)
#df['b']=df['b'].where(~m,val)
```

**Output df**

```
     a     b
0    1  10.0
1    2  10.0
2    3  10.0
3  100  50.0
```

Comment: thank you. I need the 50 in column b does not change.In your code, it was replaced with null value

Comment: then I think you need to use `Series.replace`.Please check now:)

Comment: My brain went straight to isin, was just about to comment until I saw ur post

Comment: it seems simple with replace, although I also thought of isin first @Datanovice